# Algorithm for Ranking a List by User Preference

Tags: algorithm, sorting, optimization

all.

I'm looking into getting into a new hobby and I found a massive list of a bunch of them on Reddit. However, I'm finding that some of them are mildly interesting to me whilst others are less/more so. I want to right a basic throw-away Python programme where I put all of the options into a list and have the programme provide two options from the list. I would then say whether hobby 1 or 2 sounds preferable to me before being presented with a new pair.

Naturally, there would be nCr(n, 2) ways to pick two of them which means that I could be sitting there for a while ranking them, which is a risk I'm willing to take. The problem is I want to have an algorithm for ensuring that

1. All the pairs are selected
2. The scores adjust over time

The language I'm most comfortable with is Python and that's what I do all of my programming in. Although I haven't put anything down, my initial thought would be to have a list of hobbies (call it `hobbies`) from which I'll select my pairs. I'd probably also want a dictionary of their values (call it `hobby_values` which stores each value for the hobbies as an `int` type). Essentially, I think something like the following might be a decent (if imperfect) way of doing it:

```
picked_pairs = []
while len(picked_pairs) < nCr(len(hobbies), 2):
     pair = choices(hobbies, 2)
     if pair[0] < pair[1]:
          pair[0], pair[1] = pair[1], pair[0]

     if pair in picked_pairs:
          continue
     print(f'1) {pair[0]}')
     print(f'2) {pair[1]}')
     user_preference = int(input('Which is preferable?'))

     if user_preference == 1:
          hobby_values[pair[0]] += 1
     elif user_preference == 2:
          hobby_values[pair[1]] += 1

     picked_pairs.append(pair)

hobby_values = sorted(hobby_values.values())
for k, v in hobby_values.items():
     print(f'{len(hobby_values) - v}) {k}')
```

I don't know if there's a premade function for the nCr, but if there's not, assume that I defined `nCr(n, r)` to return the necessary value.

Another way to do this would be to create a similar programe but, instead of comparing the length of `picked_pairs` to `nCr(n, 2)`, I could just create a coproduct list of all the possible pairs and then just remove all of the double pairs.

Ultimately, my question is twofold:

1. Is this optimal? If not, how can I optimise this?
2. Is there a known algorithm that can do this more efficiently or in less lines of code?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.